installing foam board insulation between fiberglass insulation and a vapor barrier and plywood wall?
I am in the process of finishing the inside of a pole shed.  I have House wrap on the outside (behind the steel), then I had fiberglass insulation and a vapor barrier put up.  I am now putting up the girts to install the finished plywood walls.  I am wondering if I can put 1 or 1.5 foam board between the girts and then the plywood?  so the finished product would be steel on the outside, then house wrap, then fiberglass insulation, then vapor barrier, then foam board then 3/4" plywood.  Wood this be OK?

When talking about vapor barriers, it helps to know if you are in Sweden or the Bahamas.  I.e. what kind of climate.  Also, is this shed conditioned?  I.e. are you heating/cooling it?
